Repeated application of the map $x \mapsto 2^x \bmod x$
Recently, I've been playing around with the map $x \mapsto 2^x \bmod x$. I calculated the smallest natural number requiring $n$ application of this map to reach $0$, and here's that sequence:
$$0, 1, 3, 18, 35, 207, 774, 1513, 2051, 8900, 13459, 25907, 34305, 88036, ...$$
Is this sequence infinite, i.e. for arbritarily large $n$, there exists a natural number requiring more than $n$ application of the map to reach $0$?

It is not clear how you defined your sequence. If you are going to iterate a function, you need to specify the starting value.

It is conjectured (see this OEIS page) that, for each positive integer $k$, there exists a positive integer $n$ for which $k=2^n\bmod n$. If this conjecture is true, your sequence will be infinite, as we can continue any sequence of iteration backwards indefinitely.

@jjagmath I think there's some confusion. The sequence on the post is not some trajectory obtained by repeatedly applying the map but rather they are the smallest starting values for which you need to iterate the map $n$ times before $0$ is reach

Upto start value $n=188\ 736\ 643$ , all values from $1$ to $27$ occur.

Start value $416\ 569\ 989$ : $28$ steps

Start value $953\ 350\ 161$ :  $29$ steps

Start value $1\ 617\ 152\ 961$ : $30$ steps
